# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS 2nd log on attempt hangs

Tags: 18.04

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 both on my VMWare Workstation 14 as well as physically on my HP laptop.

Every time after I incorrectly typed my password, my 2nd attempt with correct password the Ubuntu screen just hangs with a big purple screen.

Is it a known bug?

Comment: duplicate:https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031821/why-does-my-ubuntu-18-04-get-stuck-on-the-purple-screen-after-logging-in 
Same problem here. May be this is a bug. See the link.