# Why does my ubuntu 18.04 get stuck on the 'purple' screen after logging in?

Tags: boot, drivers, login, login-screen

Please provide me with a detailed answer explaining why my **Ubuntu 18.04** gets stuck on the purple screen after trying to log in. Is it some bug in Ubuntu or do i need to install some additional drivers or something? I have an **AMD RADEON GRAPHICS Chip** in my laptop (in addition to **intel i5**) which isn't configured yet and which might be causing this issue. Are there any **commands** I can use on that purple screen to get around it because right now i can only avoid it by performing a force shut down of the system using the power button.

Comment: The Intel i5 iGPU (integrated GPU) is supported automatically. It is the Radeon and nVidia GPUs that usually require extraordinary driver support.

Answer (score 3):

There are two relevant bug reports on the "purple screen" in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Many people have encountered difficulties including myself. However my problem seems different than the two bug reports so there might be more in the future regarding this issue.

Here are the two bug reports:

- [[regression] Password accepted but login fails (blank purple screen and mouse pointer only)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm3/+bug/1766137)
- [[regression] Ubuntu 18.04 login screen rejects a valid password on first attempt. Usually works on the second attempt](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1765261)

My problem/solution not in the bug reports was this:

- [Upgrade Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS = 5 desktop environments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029748/upgrade-ubuntu-16-04-lts-to-18-04-lts-5-desktop-environments)

Answer (score 0):

I'm having this problem with Ubuntu 18.04 on both Ubuntu Desktop version and Ubuntu Gnome version (gnome-session), however it's not related to passwords (I think). What I found is that gnome-software-service.desktop (from /etc/xdg/autostart/) takes quite a long time to load, besides other troublesome extensions. So I made a copy of it in ~/.config/autostart

`$ cp /etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-software-service.desktop  ~/.config/autostart`

and added at the end:

`X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=20
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true`

Overrall it looks like this:

`[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=GNOME Software
Exec=/usr/bin/gnome-software --gapplication-service
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
NoDisplay=true
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gnome-software
X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=20
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true`

thus delaying its start. You could also disable its start by making:

`X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true`

You can make the mods directly in `/etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-software-service.desktop` but it will get overwritten by an upgrade. The other way, the mod is only available for the user but it will always be active.