# Ubuntu 18.04 purple screen blinks

Tags: boot, grub2, 18.04

When I switch on my laptop, it boots and goes into blinking stage. Keyboard and mouse work.

After do a force shutdown using power button and boot again, this problem is gone and it boots normally.

I did boot-repair and it didn't help me either. Or is this a [common bug in 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031821/why-does-my-ubuntu-18-04-get-stuck-on-the-purple-screen-after-logging-in)

Any suggestions about installing `ubuntu-desktop` again as [suggested here](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-I-only-see-a-purple-screen-on-ubuntu-system)?

I did a version upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04. My Laptop is hp with AMD-A6 and Readon-R4 graphics.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. I'm not certain what it is, but I've found a good workaround. I turned off the splash screen and so far it's helped me. Here's a link that describes how to turn off your splash screen. I hope it helps! https://askubuntu.com/questions/248/how-can-i-show-or-hide-boot-messages-when-ubuntu-starts

Comment: I am also having the same problem when I boot with the default ubuntu version, however if I click on the option that allows me to choose the ubuntu version, and choose an earlier version then it runs fine. After booting with the earltier version, if I  "restart" (instead of power of  and then swithcing it on) and boot with default version then the problem does not occur. I did not have this problem when I initially upgraded to 18.04 but the problem  started after one of the software upgrades. I have AMD (Hp laptop) with Readon-R4 graphics.

Answer (score 3):

If you happen to have an AMD graphics card, try the solution proposed in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1032198):

> I solved it myself by using `amdgpu.dc=0` as a boot parameter.
>
> To do this, edit the file `/etc/default/grub`, for example using
>
> ```
> sudoedit /etc/default/grub
> ```
>
> Find the line beginning `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and add the text `amdgpu.dc=0` between the double quotes (`""`). Leave any other parameters as they are. For example, you may end up with a line like this:
>
> ```
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash amdgpu.dc=0"
> ```
>
> Save the file and exit, and then run
>
> ```
> sudo update-grub
> ```
>
> to write the configuration, and reboot.

Comment: Yes, that worked.

Answer (score 2):

While the Ubuntu screen was flickering I hit cntl-alt-del and it rebooted and when to the boot screen to select an OS. I selected Ubuntu and it booted without problems.

Answer (score 1):

The **easiest way** is to:

1. **Boot your Linux in ("Recovery Mode")**
2. **After going in**to **Recovery mode, select "Update GRUB"**
3. **Press** **ENTER** on "UPDATE GRUB"
4. **Reboot**

Worked for me, I had a blinking screen on my Ubuntu 18.04 with Intel graphics, but as long as you are on X drivers (by default and recommended strongly - by my opinion) you'll be fine, if not please let me know there is a way around. But, as I said, these 3-4 steps will resolve your issue with blinking splash/ boot screen when "Ubuntu is loading".

Thank you.